# String date to date (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is called `dfactual` this dataframe has a column `ForeCastEndDate`, so

```
dfactual['ForeCastEndDate'] it contains:

   311205
   311205
```

This must be a date in the format 31-12-2005, but the current format is int64. I tried the following:

```
dfactual['ForeCastEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dfactual['ForecastEndDate']))
```

I tried also to add the format command to it, but it didn't work out the format stays the same, int64.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `to_datetime` with dtypes that are not `str` so you need to convert the dtype using `astype` first and then you can use `to_datetime` and pass the format string:

```
In [154]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'ForecastEndDate':[311205]})
pd.to_datetime(df['ForecastEndDate'].astype(str), format='%d%m%y')

Out[154]:
0   2005-12-31
Name: ForecastEndDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however, if I try this: 

dfactual['ForeCastEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfactual['ForecastEndDate'].astype(str), format='%d%m%y')

It remains an int64 and not a date format, I also tried to replicate your example, but it does not work for me. What do I wrong?

Comment: You'll have to post raw input data, your python, pandas, numpy version and code that reproduces your error as this works for me

Comment: check it all over again, and it seems to work now! Do not know what I did wrong, but it works! Thanks for your help!!